# Rotate child elements of rotating div in reverse

Tags: animation, css, rotation

I have a rotating div that contains a number of divs around its edge. I'd like to give the illusion of the child divs always staying right side up. To do this I tried rotating the child divs in reverse ( `transform:rotate(-360deg);` ) but they seem to always go in the same direction as the parent div.

Is there a way have the child divs always appear right side up?

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J7xyB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

Courtesy of http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/

http://jsfiddle.net/cswkd/